# Assign value from server to html and save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, spring-restcontroller

I use spring rest.

I want to show an object and save it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public LodgerInformation createLodger(@RequestBody @Valid final LodgerInformation lodgerDto) {
    return lodgerService.save(lodgerDto);
}

public class LodgerInformation {
    private long lodgerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<IdentityCardDto> identityCardDtoList;
    ...
}



public class IdentityCardDto {
    private long identityCardId;
    private IdentityCardTypeDto identityCardTypeDto;
    private String value;
    ...
}

public class IdentityCardTypeDto {
    private long identityCardTypeId;
    private String identityCardType;
    private Date expiration;
    private boolean hasExpirationDate=false;
    ...
}
```

On the html side what is the structure i need to use for the name?
Are there some library which facilitate the process to assign value to the html component and the reverse

get answer:

"{"timestamp":1436292452811,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3f7cf4ca; line: 1, column: 11]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3f7cf4ca; line: 1, column: 11]","path":"/lodgers"}"

Comment: are you inquiring about the xml / json being sent here thats converted to the LodgerInformation ?

Comment: serialize form just don't seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The input that needs to be sent here should be of the following format

```
{
lodgerId : 1,
identityCardDtoList: [{
                        identityCardId: 11,
                        identityCardTypeDto:{
                            identityCardTypeId: 111,
                            identityCardType: "Node 1.1.1",
                            expiration: 12/12/2015,
                            hasExpirationDate: true
                            }
                       },{
                        identityCardId: 12,
                        identityCardTypeDto:{
                            identityCardTypeId: 112,
                            identityCardType: "Node 1.1.2",
                            expiration: 12/12/2015,
                            hasExpirationDate: true
                            }
                     }] 
}
```

Kindly let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: it's more how i need to name my html component. When i receive reponse from ajax call, are there library who are able to do assignation to the component... or i need to something like   $("#lodgerFirstName").val(data.firstName);

Comment: So are you inquiring how to assign value on the view page after the data is sent on the view

Comment: Like I said, my inquiring has two point.  
  
1. Component name i need to use to be able to assign value coming to the server. Also is there a way to assign value i get from server to component or i need to do manualy the assignment for every field.  
  
2. How to take the form value, build my json query and pass it to the url. Maybe there are some library to take the form value and build the json?

Comment: Want to really help you buddy but having a lot of difficulty understanding what exactly you want.

Comment: If i add a form with 50 differement input, select...  and need to send the form to a rest service. do i need to manually build the json or there are some library which can do it?

Comment: how to get this format with a form? need to take value manually and create it?

Answer (score 1):

the form would look something like this

```
 <form id="newPersonForm">
      <label for="nameInput">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="nameInput" />
      <br/>
       
      <label for="ageInput">Age: </label>
      <input type="text" name="age" id="ageInput" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Save Person" /><br/><br/>
      <div id="personFormResponse" class="green"> </div>
    </form>
```

The jquery calling code would look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Save Person AJAX Form Submit
      $('#newPersonForm').submit(function(e) {
        // will pass the form data using the jQuery serialize function
        $.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/person', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
          $('#personFormResponse').text(response);
        });
      });

    });
```

Controller Code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api")
public class PersonController {

    PersonService personService;
// handles person form submit
@RequestMapping(value="person", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String savePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    personService.save(person);
    return "Saved person: " + person.toString();
}
```

The Person object must be converted to JSON. Thanks to Spring’s HTTP message converter support, you don’t need to do this conversion manually. Because Jackson 2 is on the classpath, Spring’s MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is automatically chosen to convert the Greeting instance to JSON.
The Person object sent to the controller will mapped by the jquery creating the Person object with the help of `@RequestBody`

Comment: instead of let spring do the conversion, are there a way in js to do the conversion?

Comment: when you have many nested object, what happen if some have same name field? how the structure is automaticaly created?